# If $E, F$ are disjoint unions of rectangles, prove that $E\setminus F=\cup_{i=1}\cap_{j=1}^n(E_i-F_j)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As the the title couldn't be long enough, my question is:

if $\cup_{i=1}^nE_i, \cup_{j=1}^nF_j$ are disjoint unions of rectangles, prove that $\cup_{i=1}^nE_i\setminus \cup_{j=1}^nF_j=\cup_{i=1}\cap_{j=1}^n(E_i-F_j)$

I tried as follows:
$$if \ x\in \cup_{i=1}^nE_i\setminus \cup_{j=1}^nF_j \iff \exists i: x\in E_i\wedge x\notin \cup_{j=1}^nF_j \iff \exists i: x\in E_i\wedge x\in \cup_{j=1}^n(F_j)^c \iff \exists i: x\in E_i\wedge x\in \cap_{j=1}^n(F_j^c) \iff \exists i: x\in E_i\wedge \forall j \ x\in (F_j^c) \iff$$

With some slight changes, haven't I almost proves equivalence. How can I finnish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use De Morgan's laws for the proof? The complement of a set is denoted by superscript $c$:

$$E\setminus F = E \cap F^c = \left( \cup_{i=1}^{n} E_i \right) \cap \left( \cap_{j=1}^{m} F_j^{c}\right)$$

Note that I use separate limits for $i$ and $j$. You can further expand this to get

$$ \left( \cup_{i=1}^{n} E_i \right) \cap \left( \cap_{j=1}^{m} F_j^{c}\right) = \cup_{i=1}^n \left( E_i \cap \left( \cap_{j=1}^m F^c\right)\right)$$

moving the $E_i$ inside the inner parenthesis and create $m$ copies of $E_i$ (for a fixed $i$, you can write $E_i = \underbrace{E_i \cap \dots \cap E_i}_{m\,\text{times}}$), you obtain

$$ \cup_{i=1}^n \left( \cap_{j=1}^m \left( E_i \cap F^c\right)\right) = \cup_{i=1}^n \cap_{j=1}^m\left(E_i-F_j\right)$$

Which is almost the result you were looking for. I also didn't need to use the 'disjoint' property stated in the question, and if this is correct, then the question needs to be restated.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, but how comes $E_i=\cap_{i=1}^nE_i$?

Comment: hmmm, I see your point, this doesn't make sense. What I meant was something different. I should have written "for a fixed $i$, you can write $E_i = \underbrace{E_i \cap \dots \cap E_i}_{m\,\text{times}}$."

Comment: Ok great, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can finish with:

$...\iff\exists i:x\in E_{i}\backslash\cup_{j}F_{j}=\cap_{j}\left(E_{i}\backslash F_{j}\right)\iff x\in\cup_{i}\cap_{j}\left(E_{i}\backslash F_{j}\right)$

remark1:
You speak of *disjoint unions of rectangles*. If the unions are indeed disjoint then it follows directly that $\cup_{i}E_{i}\backslash\cup_{j}F_{j}=\cup_{i}E_{i}$. Don't you mean *unions of disjoint rectangles*?

remark2:
The fact that you are dealing with (disjoint) rectangles doesn't play any part in this. It is true for every situtation. Also if the $n$ in $\cup_j^nF_j$ is replaced by $m$ wich makes it even more general.